# subscript for a join (\bowtie) operation in LyX/LaTeX

Tags: latex, lyx, relational-algebra

I'm using LyX to write some Relational Algebra queries.
I'm using the \bowtie symbol for the join operation but when I try to put a text in subscript directly under the symbol, I get the following error:

> ...a_{\t{pId}}\t{person}\right)\bowtie\limits
>                                                      *{\t{pId}*{1}=\t{pId}_{2}... I'm ignoring this misplaced \limits or
>   \nolimits command.

Anyone knows how to do what I want? Preferably in LyX, but ERT code snippets will also be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** `\t` is a macro for `\text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `\bowtie` is not math operator such as `\int`, `\sum` etc.

Try this in preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\btie}{\bowtie}
```

and this in document:

```
\(\btie\limits_{subscript}^{superscript}\)
```

I hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: More informations are here: ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf

Comment: +1 - That's what I'd suggest too. There are many ways to make a new math operator, this is my preferred choice.

Answer (score 7):

Better use

```
\Join
```

It works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Above_and_below:

In preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

In equation:

```
\underset{your_subscript_here}{\bowtie}
```